# Operador de módulo marca error

Tags: c++

El código de la aplicación es:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void leer();
int primo(int );

int main()
{
int *x, op;
do{

 leer();
 if (primo( *x)){

     cout<<primo;
 }
     else
     cout<<"no es primo";
 cout<<"desea continuar digite 1 para si 0 para no";
 leer();
 }while (op!=0);

}
void leer(int *x)
{ cout<<"Digite numero: ";
  cin>>*x;
}
int primo(int*x)
{ int i, primo=0;
 for( i=2;i<=*x;i++){
      if (x%i=0){
      primo++;
      }

}
 if(primo=0)           
        return true;
        else;
        return false;


}
```

Error mostrado:

> ```
> $ g++ index.cpp
> index.cpp: In function ‘int primo(int*)’:
> index.cpp:30:13: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator%’
>        if (x%i=0){
>              ^
> ```

Comment: me parece que te falta el * en el if del for de la funcion primo (Y te falta un = ). para comparar es == . En el if de mas abajo tambien te esta faltando un  =

Comment: @santiago, ¿podrías comprobar si el problema es el que te indico en mi respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en que la variable `x` es un puntero a entero.

La condición `if (x%i=0){` está asignando primero el valor `0` a la variable `i` (entero), pero luego trata de calcular el resultado del módulo del puntero almacenado en `x` con `0`, cuyo resultado no es posible calcular (no se puede calcular el módulo de un puntero).

Debes usar:

```
if ((*x % i) == 0) {
```

Supongo que lo que tratas de hacer es obtener primero el valor al que apunta el puntero `x` y después calcular el módulo de su contenido con `i` para comparar el resultado con `0`.

Tu código en general no funciona, pero se puede arreglar fácilmente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void leer(int *);
int primo(int);

int main()
{
    int x;
    leer(&x);
    while (x != 0) {
        if (primo(x)){
            cout << "primo" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "no es primo" << endl;
        }
        leer(&x);
    }
    return 0;
}

void leer(int *x)
{
    cout << "Digite numero (0 para terminar): ";
    cin >> *x;
}

int primo(int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < x; i++){
        if ((x % i) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Fíjate que no espero a contar el número de veces que es divisible. En cuanto es divisible por un número inmediatamente devuelvo que no es primo.

Comment: Hecho, aunque por desgracia creo que no sacará provecho de los arreglos y los conocimientos que debería adquirir en el proceso :(

Comment: Igualmente. un placer